# Removendo o TitleBar do app android

Tags: android, android-layout

To iniciando no android, e sei muito pouco! To desenvolvendo devagar e a cada mudança eu salvo o apk e vejo ele rodando no meu celular. Observei que fica uma barra no app com o nome da aplicação! Gostaria de tirar essa barra! Vi vários tutoriais na internet, porem nenhum deu certo! Não sei se de fato estou fazendo errado ou se tem haver com a compatibilidade!

Uso o Android Studio e no theme eu coloquei "NoTitleBar", porém não funciona!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="proj.beta" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

O Title_Bar que me refiro está na seguinte imagem!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você realmente quer remover completamente a barra ou somente o título?

Comment: É a titleBar ou actionBar?

Comment: @MateusCarvalho é a titleBar mesmo, a actionBar é onde fica o relogio e os outros icones, não é?

Comment: @regmoraes quero remover completamente

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Você pode configurar pelo Manifest para deixar o app em fullScreen.

> AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

> Via código Java

```
// onCreate()
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

// setContentView()
```

Comment: fiz o que você falou, só que o aplicativo nem rodou! Deu uma mensagem de erro falando que parou de funcionar

Comment: Certo, me mande o seu manifest sem o código acima.

Comment: Certo. Vou por na pergunta

Comment: Editei a resposta.

Comment: Primeiro o código que eu deixei na resposta, e então você coloca o setContentView.

Comment: de fato o app funcionou em full screen, porém a barra do TITLE_BAR continua a mostra. A unica coisa que sumiu foi o action_bar

Comment: Mande uma imagem descrevendo o seu problema, digo o "title_bar" que voce deseja remover.

Comment: @ivanveloso, veja minha resposta novamente. Pegue o código da parte "AndroidManifest.xml" e troque no seu código.

Comment: Se preferir, troque apenas a linha: `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">`

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29107/discussion-between-ivan-veloso-and-array).

Answer (score 6):

Amigo é barbada, va em `res/values/styles.xml`

modifique `parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"` para `parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"` e faça um rebuild e pronto é só emular.

Answer (score 3):

Simples, só adicionar uma linha ao `onCreate`:

```
@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {          
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   getSupportActionBar().hide(); // Esta linha contém o código necessário.
   setContentView(R.layout.sua_activity);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode no método `onCreate()` da sua Activity

```
//Remove a title bar
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Answer (score 1):

No seu arquivo `styles.xml` vem com um tema default:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

Para remover a `ActionBar`, crie um style com o mesmo `parent` do style default, incluindo apenas o `NoActionBar`:

```
  <style name="AppThemeNoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

    </style>
```

Na Activity que você queria remover o ActionBar, acrescente o tema:

```
  <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppThemeNoActionBar" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente mudar o tema da sua activity para:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen"
```

Att. Jeiferson